# Laravel eloquent counting a relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to laravel and eloquent and I'm not sure if this is even possible. but I have 2 tables with a one to many relationship. One is "locations" and one is "users". One location can have many users.

So if I wanted to get all locations with all users I would just do this:

```
Location::with("users")->get();
```

But I also want to know how many users *each* location has, I tried doing this

```
Location::with("users")->count("users")->get();
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: What did you do so far to find out? I mean not that someone suggests something you already did.

Comment: If been checking the documentation but can't really find anything about it

Comment: If `Location::with("users")->get();` then `Location::with("users")->count();` might  work, too. Have you tried that (I've just scanned the docs, never used that library)?.

Comment: Then you would count the locations, not the users

Comment: Hmm. I see. What does `Location::with("users")->count("users")->get();` return?

Comment: Can you post your mysql db's? But I think it's job of php.

Comment: If you already loaded a relationship you can count it like `count($location->relationships['users'])` when you are looping trough the locations for example with a `foreach ($locations as $location)` Or you want to count all the users who has a location not for each?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The n+1 issue that was mentioned doesn't occur if you use eager loading.

```
$locations = Location::with('users')->get();

$locations->users()->count();
```

This should result in three queries, no matter how many users or locations you have.

- count query against the location model
- select * from locations
- select * from users where in

The confusion arises from the fact that this also works:

```
$locations = Location::all();

$locations->users()->count();
```

But in this case, it does query once for each location.

See the docs for more info:
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Although late to the party, just like to point out you still get the n+1 problem with this. You need to use `$location>users->count()` in a foreach , basically don't access the method users(), but access the property, or it does a query each time.

Comment: @David thank you so much, you helped clear up the confusion as I was still seeing an n+1 problem. It would help to update this answer to be more accurate.

Answer (score 13):

You should be using just `withCount` but I guess it wasn't available back in 2012.

So here's how it should look like:

```
Location::with("users")->withCount("users")->get();
```

And you will have an `users_count` attribute available on you object.

Read the docs for more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations (scroll down a bit and you'll see **Counting Related Models**)

Comment: You can use `withCount()` without using `with()`.

Comment: And also good to know that you also may alias the withCount result. `withCount("users as num_users")`

Answer (score 8):

You need to call the count method on each Location record to get users count per location, here is an example:

```
foreach(Location::get() as $location) // or foreach(Location::with("users")->get() as $location)
{
  echo $location->users()->count();
}
```

This should solve your problem and give you the number of users per each location. You can add a check in the loop to ignore locations with users' count = 0

Comment: Would this use as many DB queries as results from Location::get()?

Comment: This is bad. It results in a [n+1 query issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue?lq=1)

Comment: In this case, is better using Collection. Because thus you use the PHP for relationships count. `$location->users->count()`